# oracle 11g sql to generate dates between range for non working days

Tags: sql, oracle

*I have to generate dates between last working day and copy the amount to these non working days as well*
Sample below

Table1

---

```
Date       Amount
31-Dec-20  500
4-Jan-21   800
```

Expected output

```
Date      Amount
31-Dec-20 500
01-Jan-21 500
02-jan-21 500
03-jan-21 500
04-Jan-21 800
```

As 31 Dec was last working day before 4 Jan its amount has been copied over to the other days which are a holiday

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a calendar; one way is to generate it (as I did; only for several days - yours would/should be "complete". Note that you should also have a (separate?) table for holidays and/or non-working days). Then, in order to fetch amounts for days not contained in your sample data table, use a subquery with a condition that says "give me amount valid up to calendar date change).

Something like this:

```
SQL> with
  2  calendar as
  3    -- you have to have a calendar
  4    (select date '2020-12-30' + level - 1 datum
  5     from dual
  6     connect by level <= 10
  7    ),
  8  test (datum, amount) as
  9    -- your sample data
 10    (select date '2020-12-31', 500 from dual union all
 11     select date '2021-01-04', 800 from dual
 12    )
 13  -- final query; subquery returns amount valid up to calendar date change
 14  select c.datum,
 15        (select max(a.amount)
 16         from test a
 17         where a.datum <= c.datum
 18        ) as amount
 19  from calendar c
 20  order by c.datum;

DATUM          AMOUNT
---------- ----------
30.12.2020
31.12.2020        500
01.01.2021        500
02.01.2021        500
03.01.2021        500
04.01.2021        800
05.01.2021        800
06.01.2021        800
07.01.2021        800
08.01.2021        800

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```